What happens to the second strand in single-stranded / prime editing?
Articles about ’prime’ CRISPR editing generally state that a major advantage is that it only affects one strand…
…But what happens to the second, complementary strand of the genome?  Doesn’t it have to eventually change to match the first?
Or is that edited portion of the genome forever ‘open’, which would surely cause problems in replication etc.?

Of course, both DNA strands must be changed.
The way this is done can be found,for examlple, in the Wikipedia article “Prime editing”. In brief, there have been several modifications of the main approach to this, which in essence is as follows:

After the editing of one strand has been completed, a nick is
introduced in the unedited strand. The cell’s natural repair
mechanism will act on the nicked (unedited) strand and, in so doing,
copy the intact edited strand.

Details of how the specific nicking of the unedited strand is achieved can be found in the cited article.
Postscript
It is perhaps worth clarifying why editing a single strand, rather than both, is advantageous. As I am no expert in this area, I merely quote verbatim from the Wikipedia article:

“The prime editing tool offers advantages over traditional gene editing technologies. CRISPR/Cas9 edits rely on non-homologous end joining (NHEJ) or homology-directed repair (HDR) to fix DNA breaks, while the prime editing system employs DNA mismatch repair. This is an important feature of this technology given that DNA repair mechanisms such as NHEJ and HDR, generate unwanted, random insertions or deletions (INDELs).”

